# Wordpress plugin with custom post type-- how use templates from the plugin for both single post and front page views

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've written a simple Wordpress plugin that creates a custom post type (called a "river", it displays images of book covers).

I originally kept the templates for the rivers in my main theme file and followed the standard hierarchy by making a template named single-river.php, which works. I also showed the rivers interspersed with regular posts on the front page of my website by putting this inside the loop in index.php:

```
if (get_post_type() == 'post') {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content');
elseif (get_post_type() == 'river' {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/river');
}
```

I'm adding some features to the plugin, and as part of that i'd like to move all the river-related code inside the plugin instead of having it scattered around.

Adding this code to my plugin works for displaying a single river on its own page:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'river_template', 99);

function river_template($template) {
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'river' ) {
        $file_name = 'single-river.php';
        $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template/' . $file_name;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

What's the right way to specify a template part for rivers displayed on the front page/other list pages that display multiple posts, if i'm not using `get_template_part` in the loop? I've tried `is_front_page()` in the `template_include` filter without success and I'm not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: use `is_singular( 'river' )` instead of `get_post_type($post) == 'river'`

Comment: Thanks, that works on a single river. From the plugin, how can I tell it what template to use when there's a list of posts, like I have on my front page/index.php?